# JAXB 2.0 XSD choiceContentProperty wrong behavior

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, wsdl, cxf

I have this xsd schema:

```
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
       xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" jaxb:version="1.0">

<xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
        <jaxb:globalBindings choiceContentProperty="true"/>
    </xs:appinfo>
</xs:annotation>

<xs:element name="request1">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="request2">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="field1"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="request3">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="field2"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>

            <xs:element name="request4">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="field3"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>

        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

And Cxf codegen plugin generated class with `List<Object>` . But I need to get request2, request3, request4 fields with getters and setters in request1 class. It is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, setting `choiceContentProperty`to `true` causes the elements to be mapped into one property (the `List<Object>`). Setting it to `false` changes the behavior, i.e. the elements will be wrapped into individual properties.
This is explained [here](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/04/xml-schema-to-java-xsd-choice.html) in more detail.

If you can't change your XSD, you should consider using a [external bindings files](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html#wp148366).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jxb:bindings version="2.0" xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <jxb:globalBindings choiceContentProperty="false" />
</jxb:bindings>
```

Note: This behavior can only be set globally, so changing it might affect other elements as well.